# morphia and howto update existing document field

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am trying to update a document.

I cannot see/understand how to do it from this page:
[http://www.mongodb.org](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating)

My Document looks as following: (could be some error here)

```
@Entity
public class UserData {
    
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date lastUpdateDate;
    
    @Id private ObjectId id;
    public String status= "";
    public String uUid= "";


    public UserData() {
        super();
        this.statistic = new Statistic();
        this.friendList = new FriendList();
    }

    @Embedded
    private Statistic statistic;
    @Embedded
    private FriendList friendList;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.creationDate = (creationDate == null) ? new Date() : creationDate;
        this.lastUpdateDate = (lastUpdateDate == null) ? creationDate : new Date();
    }
}
```

On that page I cannot see any place where they describe how to update my `UserData` that has a specific `uUid`.

Like "update UserData.status if uUid=123567".

This is what I think I should use:

```
ops=datastore.createUpdateOperations(UserData.class).update("uUid").if uuid=foo..something more here..
```

It updates all the `UserData` documents so how to update selected ones?

```
datastore.update(datastore.createQuery(UserData.class), ops);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
query = ds.createQuery(UserData.class).field("uUid").equal("1234");
ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(UserData.class).set("status", "active");

ds.update(query, ops);
```

Comment: yes, why don't that page i refer to have that information. Or did i miss it, or is this not a normal way to address documents inside of a collection?

Answer (score 2):

The morphia interface is a little clumsy and the docs aren't clear... but **a method to update only a single, specific document is actually demonstrated on [the page Erik referenced](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating#Samples_initialization)**:

```
// This query will be used in the samples to restrict the update operations to only the hotel we just created.
// If this was not supplied, by default the update() operates on all documents in the collection.
// We could use any field here but _id will be unique and mongodb by default puts an index on the _id field so this should be fast!
Query<Hotel> updateQuery = datastore.createQuery(Hotel.class).field("_id").equal(hotel.getId());
```

**...**

```
// change the name of the hotel
ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(Hotel.class).set("name", "Fairmont Chateau Laurier");
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

---

**Also, [a different documentation page](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Datastore#Update_Methods) shows a clever way to hide that cumbersome query inside the entity class itself:**

```
@Entity
class User
{
   @Id private ObjectId id;
   private long lastLogin;
   //... other members

   private Query<User> queryToFindMe()
   {
      return datastore.createQuery(User.class).field(Mapper.ID_KEY).equal(id);
   }

   public void loggedIn()
   {
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      UpdateOperations<User> ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(User.class).set("lastLogin", now);
      ds.update(queryToFindMe(), ops);
      lastLogin = now;
   }
}
```

Comment: i like the hiding of the query you show. How would i call  the `loggedIn()` method? I do need to create a query for the specific `User` right? and then call the `loggedIn()`? Would i not have to pull out the entire `User` Object or can i shorten the java code?

Comment: @Erik: `loggedIn()` is a convenience method of the `User` class. It assumes you've already populated a `User` object with a document from the Mongo database.

There are other ways to check without pulling out the entire `User` object. Like static methods of the `User` class or implementing in a `User*DAO*` class: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/DAOSupport